# Flex Changing DataGrid Highlight Color

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, colors

How can i change the color, when the user mouse over an item on datagrid or tilelist. Basically once the user mouse overs and once the user selects a file. How to change the default color to something else.

The default is blue and i dont like it :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most powerful tool to manage about graphics effects, color and much more is [Flex Style Explorer](http://examples.adobe.com/flex3/consulting/styleexplorer/Flex3StyleExplorer.html), which is useful to create .css style sheets for you own Flex/Air application. You can export the .css properties into your Flex project, create yourStyleSheet.css, put it into src folder and than call the file by the following statement:

```
<mx:Application ... />
<mx:Style source="yourStyleSheet.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the styles for those items, the setting is rollOverColor. If you added those controls through mxml you can just add those as attributes.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using CSS to layout your Flex components you might want to have a lock at the [Flex 3 Style Explorer](http://examples.adobe.com/flex3/consulting/styleexplorer/Flex3StyleExplorer.html). You can setup your layout for specific components and directly export the CSS code either to your external stylesheet or your  tags within your mxml code. Hope this helps.